# Cadence Hal linting

Tags: verilog

So while running linting you can write your own exclusion file. In this file you can indicate module names and it will exclude the module and ALL of the modules that it uses. So lets say i have *top_old* and *top_new*. They use some of the same modules but I want to exclude *top_old* the mutual files will be excluded as well which is not what I want.

I just want to exclude the file top_old and not all of the files that it uses.

So when you are creating the exclusion file you use:

```
designunit = top_old;
```

(which is the module name)

what I am wondering is if there is a way to do:

```
file = top_old.v;
```

and have it only exclude the file and nothing else

Comment: yeah they pointed me to the hal user guide, which looks like it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the best way to do this is as follows:

where ever you have your `bb_list{...}` include a section that is `gb_list{...}`

so the file looks like this

```
bb_list{

   designunit = dut;

}

gb_list{

   designunit = dut2;

}
```

dut2 will be excluded from the linting but all of the modules that it instantiates will still be linted.